# how to let program show correct version number in source control?

Tags: c, version-control, makefile

I wish my C program show correct version keep in mercurial source control.  My method exist some problems.

1. If I modify other.c, the version can not display correct.
2. If I modify main.c without check in, I wish make will warn me.
3. There are many files in separate directories.  I wish I could change the version only when the dependency files changed.

By the way, I don't care which version control system is used, just wonder are these problems could be solved.

main.c

```
int main() {
  printf("version=%s\n", VERSION);
  return 0;
}
```

makefile

```
VERSION=$(shell hg id -i)
# PHONY force main.c always compile
.PHONY: main.c
all: main
main: main.o other.o
    gcc main.o other.o -o main
main.o : main.c
    gcc -c -DVERSION=\"${VERSION}\" main.c -o main.o
other.o : other.c
    gcc -c other.c -o other.o
```

For my first question, Carl Norum provide a solution to use PHONY, this method has side effect, it will always build main.c and executable **main** even there is no modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard solution to your first problem is to create a file (say config.h) with the system configuration and changing global variables such as VERSION. main can then include config.h. You can edit config.h by hand or have config.h rebuilt from Makefile flags a rule like:

```
config.h : force-rebuild
    sed -e 's/[@]VERSION[@]/$(VERSION)/' $<.in > $@

.PHONY : force-rebuild
```

where your template file config.h.in contains "@VERSION@" wherever the version number should go.

Your version control system should handle the second problem. `svn status` and similar commands handle this just fine.

For the third problem there is no standard solution since most version bumping rules require human interaction. When you tagged your old version properly, you can just compare two versions in your version control; e.g. for SVN:

```
svn diff $MYREPO/tags/$CURRENT_VERSION .
```

and look at the difference. $MYREPO can be scraped from the output of `svn info` and CURRENT_VERSION from config.h.

Comment: For my third question. Do you mean, before I pass my program to test team, I should mark a tag or make a branch.  Then put the tag or branch's name on version for the test team?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want your version string to stay up to date, you're going to need to build the file that contains it every time.  In your case, that means building `main.c`, even if there's nothing out of date.  You could make `main.o` a phony target, and that would do it for you.  If `main.c` gets complicated and building it every time slows you down too much, you might think about putting the version information into a separate file and just build that one.
2. `make` has no way to handle your request on its own, but presumably your version control system can tell you if you have not-checked-in files.  You could add a check for that to any of your recipes and exit in case of failure.  Here's an example (for git, I don't know mercurial):

   ```
   allcheckedin:
       @if [[ -n $$(git status -s) ]]        ;\
        then                                  \
            echo "All files not checked in." ;\
            exit 1                           ;\
        fi
   ```

I'm not sure I fully understand your third question - if you can clarify it, I'll try to help you out.

Comment: thanks your hint, but have you ever do such thing, could you give me the sample Makefile?

Comment: I added an example for #2 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like *SVN* or *CVS* for version control. Then use the `what` format (see man what) to place a static string in each .c or .cpp file incorporating a version that either version system can place in it automatically.

i.e.

```
static const char[] = "@(#) $Id$"); /* For example SVN */
```

They you can use the utility `what` for find out exactly the versions for all files in the build.

Comment: Well, this method have two disadvantages. First, will reduce the performance of source version control system.  So, git,hg don't support this method by default.  Second, this method will let compare with old source code always show different. Especially when your source code stored on multiple repositories.